# Espresso not finding test apk

Tags: android, debugging, path, apk, android-espresso

Im building a test suite for my app, but keep getting the following error when trying to run a test on an emulator:

> $ adb push /Users/me/dev/Android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/myApp.debug
>
> $ adb shell pm install -t -r "/data/local/tmp/myApp.debug"
>       pkg: /data/local/tmp/myApp.debug
>   Success
>
> **The APK file /Users/me/dev/Android/app/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/app-debug-androidTest.apk does not exist on disk.
>   Error while Installing APK**

The real debug file i want the tests to run against is located at:

> /Users/me/dev/Android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk

I have the following setup in gradle:

```
    android.defaultConfig {
       testInstrumentationRunner 
    'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }

    ...
    dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.1'

    // Espresso support
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    // add this for intent mocking support
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.0.1'
    }
```

Any idea how i can configure the test runner to look for the debug apk in the correct directory?

Thanks in advance :)

UPDATE -
Things i have tried already are:

1. ./gradlew connecteAndroidTest
2. ./gradlew assembleDebug
3. ./gradlew assembleDebugAndroidTest
4. Creating a new test runner from Edit Configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of reading i determined it wasn't something that could be configured and something was funky with Android Studio, invalidating the caches and restarting fixed it :)